# What is the way to express Yang-Mills symmetry groups without gauges?

Tags: gauge-theory, gauge-invariance, yang-mills, gauge

Given a Yang-Mills theory such as $SU(3)$ which has 8 gluons. After we gauge-fix this theory, it no longer has $SU(3)$ guage symmetry. Yet, we still use the group constants and the 8 types of gluons to calculate the Feynman graphs.

Thus the gauge-fixed action still retains some sort of $SU(3)$-ness to it even though it is not a local symmetry any more.

In the gauge-fixed action, what is the name of this $SU(3)$-ness?

It's like we start with a guage theory with group $G$, then gauge-fix it to remove the guage freedoms, but are left with a shadow of the group $G$.

i.e. we could still classify all gauge-fixed Yang-Mills actions by a group $G$.

So what is the relation of the gauge group to the gauge-fixed action?

Comment: After removing the gauge freedom, there is still a global $SU(3)$ symmetry, and that's what relates the different gluons.

Comment: @knzhou I see, so with gauge-fixing you are making the symmetry act in the same way for all points in space-time turning the local symmetry into a global symmetry?

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/508368/2451