# What is a 'potential' in the context of physics and gauge symmetry?

Tags: potential, field-theory, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance

I heard someone say that the definition of a gauge transformation is any formal, systematic transformation of the potentials that leaves the fields invariant. What is the definition of a potential in the context of fields (such as QFT)? If possible, in layman's terms.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the notion of [gauge theories](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8686/2451) is much more general than, say, [Yang-Mills theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yang%E2%80%93Mills_theory). There is of course a long list of gauge theories that have gauge potentials -- e.g. in the case of Yang-Mills theory, the $A^a_{\mu}(x)$ field is the gauge potential -- but it is not a general requirement for a gauge theory.

Answer (score 0):

The non-derivative terms of a field $\phi$ in the Lagrangian are often (not always) collectively called its "potential" $V(\phi)$. This is because in field theory, the field $\phi$ is the analog of coordinates $q$ particle mechanics, and there potential functions usually contain powers of $q$.In the context of electromagnetism, the field $A^\mu$ itself is a potential, called electromagnetic four-potential $A^\mu=(\phi/c,\textbf{A})$.