# Is this the most general form for a gauge transformation?

Tags: field-theory, terminology, gauge-theory, definition, gauge-invariance

From my understanding, a gauge transformation in QFT is a local transformation in the fields under which the action is invariant. I usually write it, for a theory with scalars, fermions, and vector bosons, as:
$\Phi\rightarrow \Phi'=\Phi$
$\psi\rightarrow \psi'=U(x)\psi$
$A_\mu\rightarrow A_\mu'=A_\mu + \frac{1}{g}U(x)^{-1}\partial_\mu U(x)$
$\Rightarrow S\rightarrow S'=S$

*(first question, just to make sure: is this correct?)*
Real question, **is this the most general gauge transformation I can write using only these fields?** Can I use something more general than a transformation matrix $U(x)$?

Comment: Related: [Nomenclature: Yang-Mills theory vs Gauge theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8686/2451)

Comment: There certainly are more possibilities. For one, why would scalars be invariant? The Higgs field isn't, for example.

Comment: A gauge transformation as you've written it is all classical, there's nothing quantum about it.

Comment: In addition to the other comments here, I'll note that the transformation you've written for $A_\mu$ is only correct for $U(1)$ (Maxwell) gauge theory. For a non-abelian gauge group, this would be incorrect.